# App page used to resolve from Facebook search, now it 4oh4's

Tags: facebook, http-status-code-404, facebook-page

I have an existing facebook app. I can search for it from the "search" box on the facebook site.

It used to resolve just fine. Now even though I still see the app in search results I get a 4oh4 error when clicking on the app link.

Everything else works just fine, the app works, the link to visit app from developer section works.

The id's are the same but the facebook search link seems to have slightly different URL.

The search I did was for ClubView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plug a URL into the Bookmark URL field:
[image]

This is a [bug logged with Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/204664672932552) and that is the known workaround.

Answer (score 0):

This one is very easy, your app is in sandbox mode that means only developers can see it, and if you are not logged as a developer it will show you 4oh4's error page. Your welcome! :)

Comment: Sorry but I was logged in as me, who IS the developer. And as mentioned it used to work fine before....and still could be seen i the search results...just would not resolve. 

It turns out I can answer my own question with what might be a known bug or issue but who knows..... my co-founder on this project last night created a fan page which the exact same name as the application. Once he unpublished the fan page, the search hit resolved again to the app. Apparently you cannot have a page and an app have the same name.

Comment: Usually fan pages only can have their own name after having more than 25 fans, and they doesn't share the same nomenclature so I don't see how this could be an issue.

https://apps.facebook.com/myNameHere    (apps uri)
https://www.facebook.com/myNameHere    (fan page uri)

Has you can see both uri's are totally diferent should not cause any  conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I can see your app in the search results and click on it without issue.  If you just recently submitted the app for search, then maybe the URL didn't have a chance to properly propagate to all of Facebook's servers.